Entering into the last modified sub-directory in a directory in linux
I have a dir in which I keep adding new dirs from a script. I want to enter that new sub-dir directly rather that always manually doing eza --sort=modified then copy pasting that name then cd into that folder.
I am using eza and zoxide in fish shell
I tried doing this:
eza --sort=modified | tail -n 1 | xargs z 
But it just gave an error xargs: z: No such file or directory. I did a bit of digging and now understand that pipe runs xargs in a subprocess, and xargs runs zoxide in a subprocess and changes in a subprocess do not get propagated to the parent process.
I then tried:
z "(eza  --sort=modified | tail -n 1 )"
I still got zoxide: no match found

Why not cd $(ls -drt */ | tail -n 1)? Or something similar? I don't have eza to test, but ls works fine.

This worked thanks

As mentioned by @David C. Rankin in the comments:
z ( eza --sort=modified | tail -n 1) worked
